# How does parachain upgrade works?

Tags: parachain, runtime, storage, runtime-upgrade, fee

Let we have a running parachain on kusama and want to do a runtime upgrade. New runtime is bigger then the old one by 100 kb. New runtime will be stored on the relay chain after runtime upgrade therefore someone have to deposit fee for additional storage usage. Is it right? Who have to pay and how to calculate fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a "system" call, the fee is a constant small value. And it's free on relaychain side.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/f6ae145813b2e213b39f09f713d3ccbdd9376f6b/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L703

Comment: Thanks! Then how relay chain controls parachain runtime size? Does it? I guess there is a code size limit or something. Is it maxCodeSize from pallet configuration?